# Assign return value when index check out of bounds

Tags: rust

In pseudo-code, I'm trying the following:

```
for i in len(array):
    try:
        a = array[i-1]
    except(out_of_bounds_error):
        a = false
```

where `array` is just made up of booleans.

In the book (Chapter 9.2) it says you can check whether a function returns a result or not with something like:

```
let a: u32 = array[i-1]
```

which tells me `a` is indeed a bool. Without a `Result` type, how do I handle the inevitable (and expected) `attempt to subtract with overflow` error at runtime?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use `if`, e.g. `let a = if i > 0 { array[i - 1] } else { false }`

Comment: @loganfsmyth No reason, so your answer is great, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The error `attempt to subtract with overflow` occurs when computing `i - 1` when `i == 0`. Array indices must be of type `usize`, which is an unsigned type, and unsigned types cannot represent negative numbers, which `0 - 1` would produce. In a debug build, the compiler generates code that raises this error, but in a release build, the compiler generates code that will simply compute the "wrong" value (in this case, this happens to be `usize::max_value()`).

You can avoid this error in both debug builds and release builds by performing a checked subtraction instead. [`checked_sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_sub) returns an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html): you'll get a `Some` if the subtraction succeeded or `None` if it failed. You can then use [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) on that `Option` to read the array only if the subtraction produced a valid index.

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![true; 10];

    for i in 0..a.len() {
        let b = i.checked_sub(1).map_or(false, |j| a[j]);
        println!("b: {}", b);
    }
}
```

Arrays (or rather, slices) also have a [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get) method that returns an `Option` if the index is out of bounds, instead of panicking. If we were adding one to the index, instead of subtracting one, we could do this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![true; 10];

    for i in 0..a.len() {
        let b = i.checked_add(1).and_then(|j| a.get(j).cloned()).unwrap_or(false);
        println!("b: {}", b);
    }
}
```

This time, we're using `and_then` to chain an operation that produces an `Option` with another operation that also produces an `Option`, and we're using `unwrap_or` to get the `Option`'s value or a default value if it's `None`.